# POS Tagging in R

Tags: performance, r

I would like to do POS tagging on around 8,000 tweets. I have a function and am using data.table to call it on every row. The problem I'm having is that it takes over 1.5hours to run this chunk of code.

Code:

```
options(java.parameters = "- Xmx3000m")
library(rJava)
library(NLP)
library(openNLP)
library(data.table,quietly = TRUE)

dat[,c("ID"):= .I]
dat[,c("POS"):= tagPOS(strip(Tweet)),by = .(ID)]

tagPOS =  function(x) {
    s <- as.String(x)

    sent_token_annotator = Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
    word_token_annotator = Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
    a2 = annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
    pos_tag_annotator = Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator()
    a3 = annotate(s, pos_tag_annotator, a2)
    a3w = subset(a3, type == "word")
    POStags = unlist(lapply(a3w$features, `[[`, "POS"))
    gc()
    return(paste(POStags,collapse = " "))
}
```

Comment: Not familiar with POS tagging. Could the three Maxent annotator objects be shared by the functions calls (i.e. define them outside the function and pass them as arguments)? Or are these objects affected by the way they are used at each iteration?

Comment: @flodel Good call, it's down to 9 minutes now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I put that in an answer that also shows you how to use the profiler, which could have put you on the right track. Unrelated, if you happen to know of a good tutorial or presentation that shows the kind of things that can be done with `openNLP`, I wouldn't mind having a look. For my own curiosity. Thanks!

Comment: @flodel This is my first program with NLP so I really don't have much info on openNLP. I've just been using the help files so far, but they are pretty detailed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best tool to diagnose slow code is the profiler. Here is how you could run it on a few function calls to see what is slowing down the execution of your code:

```
Rprof(tmp <- tempfile())
for (i in 1:10) tagPOS(strip(dat$Tweet[i]))
Rprof()
summaryRprof(tmp)
unlink(tmp)
```

Supposedly (from our comments), this would show that most of the computation time is spent creating the annotators. Since these are independent of the sole input `x` of your function, you could save a lot of time by defining them outside your function and passing them as arguments:

```
annotators <- list(sent_token = Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator(),
                   word_token = Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator(),
                   pos_tag    = Maxent_POS_Tag_Annotator())

tagPOS <- function(x, ann = annotators) {
  s <- as.String(x)
  a2 <- annotate(s, list(ann$sent_token, ann$word_token))
  a3 <- annotate(s, ann$pos_tag, a2)
  a3w <- subset(a3, type == "word")
  POStags <- unlist(lapply(a3w$features, `[[`, "POS"))
  gc()
  return(paste(POStags,collapse = " "))
}
```